# node.js global modules path not accessible in node scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am deploying a WordPress site which has a bunch of custom mu-plugins and custom theme, and they all have gulp build processes and all use the exact same npm packages.  Because of this, I want to install all the npm packages globally, so that I can run a root level node script which will in turn run each of the gulp files (themes and plugins) and build out all the things. Just using the node `child_process.execSync()` to run the sub gulp files.

Unfortunately it doesnt seem that my scripts can find the globally install npm packages.  my `.bashrc` script defines the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm-global/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
NODE_PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm-global/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/bin/npm-global/
```

and if i run npg -g prefix and npm -g root i get the following:

```
$ npm -g prefix
/usr/local/bin/npm-global

$ npm -g root
/usr/local/bin/npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

however, if I run my node script, I get errors like `Error: Cannot find module 'glob'`

I CAN get my scripts to work if I add something like

`module.paths.push('/usr/local/bin/npm-global/lib/node_modules')` to my main script, but I would also have to add that to every gulp file as well.  I should also point out, that if i run something like `child_process.execSync('npm -g root')` it outputs `/usr/local/bin/npm-global/lib/node_modules`

So how can I get all my scripts to just use the globally installed packages by default?

Comment: Have you tried adding `export` to your PATH/NODE_PATH definitions in .bashrc, i.e. `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm-global/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share a common `node_modules` directory for all your projects on the system by [setting the `NODE_PATH` environment variable](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders). Your `.bashrc` is setting that variable, but you can/should check that it's set in the script itself. (Maybe you're running it as a different user or in a different subshell? Maybe you're on a macOS and recently switch to zsh and are loading things from a different rc? Maybe there's a missing `export` at the start of the line that defines `NODE_PATH`?)

The most direct way to troubleshoot would be to have your script check the value of `process.env.NODE_PATH`. If it's empty or not set, that's your problem.

You can also invoke your scripts with a specific `NODE_PATH` like this: `NODE_PATH=/the/path/you/want node script.js`.